# Writing an Array to EEPROM Problem

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, proteus, eeprom

When I write an array to EEPROM and read it I always get 0xFF.
I am writing in addres 0x0001 to 0x0005.
The password I am entering is 1,1,1,1,1 saved in `uint8` array of 5 elements.
This is the project I am working on, I am interfacing two MCs with UART, and using I2C to interface the second MC with the EEPROM.

[image]

This is the code block I use to send the data to the second MC.

```
/*Send the password to MC2 to save it to EEPROM*/
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                UART_sendByte('@');
            }
            UART_sendByte(g_password[i]);
        }
```

and here is how I receive it by second MC.

```
/*Receive the password and save it to the EEPROM*/
        if(status == '@'){
            /*Receive data*/
            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                pass[i] = UART_recieveByte();
            }

            /*save data*/
            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                EEPROM_writeByte(++address, pass[i]); /* Write 0x0F in the external EEPROM */
            }

            status = 0;
        }
```

and this is how I read it again to send it to MC1 to check if the entered password is matching or not.

```
/*Send the saved password to MC1*/
        if(status == 'S'){
            address = 0x0000;

            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                EEPROM_readByte(++address, &pass[i]);
            }

            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                UART_sendByte(pass[i]);
            }

            status = 0;

        }
```

here is the I2C and EEPROM drivers.

```
#include "i2c.h"

void TWI_init(void)
{
    /* Bit Rate: 400.000 kbps using zero pre-scaler TWPS=00 and F_CPU=8Mhz */
    TWBR = 0x02;
    TWSR = 0x00;
    
    /* Two Wire Bus address my address if any master device want to call me: 0x1 (used in case this MC is a slave device)
       General Call Recognition: Off */
    TWAR = 0b00000010; // my address = 0x01 :) 
    
    TWCR = (1<<TWEN); /* enable TWI */
}

void TWI_start(void)
{
    /* 
     * Clear the TWINT flag before sending the start bit TWINT=1
     * send the start bit by TWSTA=1
     * Enable TWI Module TWEN=1 
     */
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTA) | (1 << TWEN);
    
    /* Wait for TWINT flag set in TWCR Register (start bit is send successfully) */
    while(BIT_IS_CLEAR(TWCR,TWINT));
}

void TWI_stop(void)
{
    /* 
     * Clear the TWINT flag before sending the stop bit TWINT=1
     * send the stop bit by TWSTO=1
     * Enable TWI Module TWEN=1 
     */
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTO) | (1 << TWEN);
}

void TWI_write(uint8 data)
{
    /* Put data On TWI data Register */
    TWDR = data;
    /* 
     * Clear the TWINT flag before sending the data TWINT=1
     * Enable TWI Module TWEN=1 
     */ 
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
    /* Wait for TWINT flag set in TWCR Register(data is send successfully) */
    while(BIT_IS_CLEAR(TWCR,TWINT));
}

uint8 TWI_readWithACK(void)
{
    /* 
     * Clear the TWINT flag before reading the data TWINT=1
     * Enable sending ACK after reading or receiving data TWEA=1
     * Enable TWI Module TWEN=1 
     */ 
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWEA);
    /* Wait for TWINT flag set in TWCR Register (data received successfully) */
    while(BIT_IS_CLEAR(TWCR,TWINT));
    /* Read Data */
    return TWDR;
}

uint8 TWI_readWithNACK(void)
{
    /* 
     * Clear the TWINT flag before reading the data TWINT=1
     * Enable TWI Module TWEN=1 
     */
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
    /* Wait for TWINT flag set in TWCR Register (data received successfully) */
    while(BIT_IS_CLEAR(TWCR,TWINT));
    /* Read Data */
    return TWDR;
}

uint8 TWI_getStatus(void)
{
    uint8 status;
    /* masking to eliminate first 3 bits and get the last 5 bits (status bits) */
    status = TWSR & 0xF8;
    return status;
}
```

and this is the .h file of I2C

```
#ifndef I2C_H_
#define I2C_H_

#include "micro_config.h"
#include "std_types.h"
#include "common_macros.h"

/*******************************************************************************
 *                      Preprocessor Macros                                    *
 *******************************************************************************/
/* I2C Status Bits in the TWSR Register */
#define TW_START         0x08 // start has been sent
#define TW_REP_START     0x10 // repeated start 
#define TW_MT_SLA_W_ACK  0x18 // Master transmit ( slave address + Write request ) to slave + Ack received from slave
#define TW_MT_SLA_R_ACK  0x40 // Master transmit ( slave address + Read request ) to slave + Ack received from slave
#define TW_MT_DATA_ACK   0x28 // Master transmit data and ACK has been received from Slave.
#define TW_MR_DATA_ACK   0x50 // Master received data and send ACK to slave
#define TW_MR_DATA_NACK  0x58 // Master received data but doesn't send ACK to slave

/*******************************************************************************
 *                      Functions Prototypes                                   *
 *******************************************************************************/
void TWI_init(void);
void TWI_start(void);
void TWI_stop(void);
void TWI_write(uint8 data);
uint8 TWI_readWithACK(void); //read with send Ack
uint8 TWI_readWithNACK(void); //read without send Ack
uint8 TWI_getStatus(void);


#endif /* I2C_H_ */
```

this is the .c file of EEPROM

```
#include "i2c.h"
#include "external_eeprom.h"

void EEPROM_init(void)
{
    /* just initialize the I2C(TWI) module inside the MC */
    TWI_init();
}

uint8 EEPROM_writeByte(uint16 u16addr, uint8 u8data)
{
    /* Send the Start Bit */
    TWI_start();
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_START)
        return ERROR;
        
    /* Send the device address, we need to get A8 A9 A10 address bits from the
     * memory location address and R/W=0 (write) */
    TWI_write((uint8)(0xA0 | ((u16addr & 0x0700)>>7)));
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MT_SLA_W_ACK)
        return ERROR; 
         
    /* Send the required memory location address */
    TWI_write((uint8)(u16addr));
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MT_DATA_ACK)
        return ERROR;
        
    /* write byte to eeprom */
    TWI_write(u8data);
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MT_DATA_ACK)
        return ERROR;

    /* Send the Stop Bit */
    TWI_stop();
    
    return SUCCESS;
}

uint8 EEPROM_readByte(uint16 u16addr, uint8 *u8data)
{
    /* Send the Start Bit */
    TWI_start();
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_START)
        return ERROR;
        
    /* Send the device address, we need to get A8 A9 A10 address bits from the
     * memory location address and R/W=0 (write) */
    TWI_write((uint8)((0xA0) | ((u16addr & 0x0700)>>7)));
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MT_SLA_W_ACK)
        return ERROR;
        
    /* Send the required memory location address */
    TWI_write((uint8)(u16addr));
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MT_DATA_ACK)
        return ERROR;
        
    /* Send the Repeated Start Bit */
    TWI_start();
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_REP_START)
        return ERROR;
        
    /* Send the device address, we need to get A8 A9 A10 address bits from the
     * memory location address and R/W=1 (Read) */
    TWI_write((uint8)((0xA0) | ((u16addr & 0x0700)>>7) | 1));
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MT_SLA_R_ACK)
        return ERROR;

    /* Read Byte from Memory without send ACK */
    *u8data = TWI_readWithNACK();
    if (TWI_getStatus() != TW_MR_DATA_NACK)
        return ERROR;

    /* Send the Stop Bit */
    TWI_stop();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

this is the .h file

```
#ifndef EXTERNAL_EEPROM_H_
#define EXTERNAL_EEPROM_H_

#include "std_types.h"

/*******************************************************************************
 *                      Preprocessor Macros                                    *
 *******************************************************************************/
#define ERROR 0
#define SUCCESS 1

/*******************************************************************************
 *                      Functions Prototypes                                   *
 *******************************************************************************/
void EEPROM_init(void);
uint8 EEPROM_writeByte(uint16 u16addr,uint8 u8data);
uint8 EEPROM_readByte(uint16 u16addr,uint8 *u8data);
 
#endif /* EXTERNAL_EEPROM_H_ */
```

this is what happens inside I2C when I run it on proteus.
this is what happens when I save the data, don't look at the first two lines they are working well.

[image]

and this is what happens when I read it.
also don't look at the first two lines.

[image]

Comment: most EEPROMs require: 1) a chip enable signal  2) after writing, a read status loop until the EEPROM is NOT busy

Comment: Actually it looks like you are sending `@1111`...

Comment: EEPROM needs some time to write the data into memory, make sure you make a significant pause, between writing and reading and check the writing timings on the datasheet.

Comment: I am sure I am getting the right number, and I made a delay up to 50ms, and nothing changed.

Comment: Basic trouble-shooting means narrowing down the problem. The problem won't be both the I2C communication _and_ the EEPROM driver, it will be either one (unless there are several problems). Verify that the correct data is sent correctly with your oscilloscope, then take it from there.

Comment: Can you make sure that you write these bytes into the addresses 1 to 5? For example, capture their write sequences? (It looks as if you're just simulating...) I'm missing the statement `address = 0x0000;` in your writing code.

Comment: I removed the code block of read and write to eeprom that are working properly from the code (the first two lines of the i2c debug pic) and compiled my code and it worked. It seems when I do previous operations of reading or writing to the memory (not sure yet what is the problem) it makes some problems.

Comment: I knew the problem, I put a delay time of 10ms between the two MC beside between every read and write and it worked. It seems that the missing delay time between the two MC was the problem. I was sending two signs by the UART of two operations to happen in MC2 and both are an I2C operations and I think there was some kind of interfering.